Sending messages on behalf of a user via Telegram bot. How?
I am developing a Telegram bot in Python 3.12 using AIogram 3.x and Pyrogram 2.0.106 frameworks. I have a problem with user authorisation.
The code I'm using is running erratically: sometimes the code fails to submit, and sometimes other errors occur. However, the main problem, after which the code never goes farther, is the [400 CODE_EXPIRED] error. Although after receiving the code before sending it to my chatbot it takes maximum 10 seconds. And by idea, the code should be valid.
Here is my code:
from aiogram import Router, F, types
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

from pyrogram import Client

class UserAuth(StatesGroup):
    waiting_for_phone = State()
    waiting_for_code = State()


@router.callback_query(lambda cq: cq.data == "add_user")
async def add_user_callback(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await callback_query.answer()
    await callback_query.message.answer("Please enter your phone number:")
    await state.set_state(UserAuth.waiting_for_phone)


@router.message(UserAuth.waiting_for_phone)
async def process_phone(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    phone_number = message.text.strip()
    await state.update_data(phone=phone_number)

    client = Client("user_session", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)
    await client.connect()

    try:
        sent_code = await client.send_code(phone_number)
        phone_code_hash = sent_code.phone_code_hash

        print(phone_code_hash)
        await message.answer("Code has been sent to your phone. Please enter the code in format: code12345")
        await state.update_data(sent_code=sent_code)
        await state.update_data(phone_code_hash=phone_code_hash)
        await state.set_state(UserAuth.waiting_for_code)
    except Exception as e:
        await message.answer(f"Failed to send code: {e}")
        await state.clear()


@router.message(UserAuth.waiting_for_code)
async def process_code(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    code = message.text.strip()
    data = await state.get_data()
    phone_number = data.get("phone")
    phone_code_hash = data.get("phone_code_hash")

    client = Client("user_session", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)
    await client.connect()

    try:
        await client.sign_in(phone_number=str(phone_number), phone_code_hash=str(phone_code_hash), phone_code=code)
        await message.answer("Authorization successful! Now you can send messages.")
        await state.clear()

        await client.send_message(chat_id, "You have successfully logged in via the bot!")
    finally:
        await state.clear()
        await client.disconnect()

I have tried using Telephon or other frameworks for my task, but as far as I am concerned, pyrogram fits best here
